# Implementing the Extended Euclidean Algorithm in a functional language

Tags: algorithm, ocaml

I'm trying to implement the Extended Euclidean Algorithm in OCaml and, trying to basically copy [this Haskell implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582754/implementing-extended-euclidean-algorithm) with slight modification (returning the GCD as well as the Bezout coefficients), I wrote the following.

```
(* A function to help get the quotient and remainder. *)
let rec quot_help a b q = 
    if (a = b*q) then q
    else if (a > b*q) then quot_help a b (q+1)
    else q-1;;

(* A function to get the quotient and remainder, as a pair. *)
let rec quotrem a b = let q = quot_help a b 0 in (q, a - b*q);; 

(* A helper to the main function. Most of the work is done here.*)    
let rec step a b s t u v =
    if (b = 0) then (a, 1, 0)
    else let (q, r) = quotrem a b in
    step b r u v (s - q*u) (t - q*v);;

let extEuc a b = step a b 1 0 0 1;; 


(* For printing an example. *)
let (q, r) = quotrem 5 3 in Printf.printf "%d, %d" q r;;
print_string "\n";;
let (o1, o2, o3) = extEuc 5 3 in Printf.printf "%d, %d, %d" o1 o2 o3;;
```

However, this always prints out `1, 1, 0` for any inputs to `extEuc`.  I can't figure out why.

I also can't understand how the Euclidean Algorithm works here. I can do the Euclidean algorithm on paper, substituting the remainder from one equation to another and collecting coefficients.  But for all that I've read on the Euclidean Algorithm, I can't connect that process to the coefficients that are getting passed around in code that implements the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, your `step` function explicitly returns `(a, 1, 0)` for all inputs. The value of `a` is the correct gcd, but obviously 1 and 0 can't be the Bezout coefficients for all cases.

Note that your function does not always return (1, 1, 0) as you claim. It does if the two numbers are relatively prime (like 5 and 3). But not for other cases:

```
 # extEuc 55 5;;
 - : int * int * int = (5, 1, 0)
```

Most likely if you fix up the value of `step` when b = 0, you'll start getting good answers.